# Запрос INSERT

Tags: sql-server, sql

Здравствуйте.

В MS SQL Server 2008 делаю простой запрос:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.gmesh_sv  VALUES ( '450', '95157', '0', '294.3', '412.0', '539.6', '9.00', '0.00', '38.00', '0.00', '0', '0', '0','0', 'IKXU')
```

Выдает ошибку: Invalid object name 'dbo.gmesh_sv'.
Хотя такая таблица в базе существует и запрос, например, на удаление, обрабатывается нормально.

Answer (score 2):

убедитесь, что переключились в контекст базы с этой таблицей. принудительно напишите сначала USE <имя базы>

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте, просто указать имя таблицы "gmesh_sv"